# How to create generic of my generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following interfaces

```
interface CollectionResponse<T> {
    count: number;
    response: T
}

interface ApiResponse {
    id: string;
    isTheUserAdmin: boolean;
}

type generic = CollectionResponse<ApiResponse>;

const obj: generic = {
    count: 1,
    response: {
        id: '1',
        isTheUserAdmin: true,
    }
}
```

so now my generic type is implement dynamically the `ApiResponse T`.

But i have more nested structure for example when i git my API i get

```
{
count: 1,
response: {
        id: '1',
        isTheUserAdmin: true,
        data: {
           linkTypes: string[],
           folderTypesIds: number[]
        }
}
}
```

so when i create my first generic `type generic = CollectionResponse<ApiResponse>;`

i need to pass another generic for my `data` property that is actually inside my response generic

so i will have this interface

```
interface Data {
     linkTypes: string[],
     folderTypesIds: number[]
}
```

how can i include that in ApiReponse on the fly so at the end i will get type check for data also
that is inside the `response` property

Comment: With more generics type paramters. Does [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/w17p8m) meet your needs? If so I can explain what's going on there as an answer.

Comment: I understant the anwer.Thank you

Comment: Can't we btw insert all of this in one line ? The generic of the generic or it is impossible ?

Comment: One line how? Which lines do want to combine?

Comment: You helped me with your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a generic `ApiResponse`.

```
interface ApiResponse<T> {
    id: string;
    isTheUserAdmin: boolean;
    data: T;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
const myApiResponse = ApiResponse<{ hello: boolean }> {
    id: '1',
    isTheUserAdmin: true,
    data: {
        hello: true
    }
}
```

Now your `Generic` type needs to also be generic in order to pass that type through.

```
type Generic<T> = CollectionResponse<ApiResponse<T>>;
```

Now you pass your api response data type to that and it will end up in the right place.

```
interface MyDataType {
  linkTypes: string[]
  folderTypesIds: number[]
}

const obj: Generic<MyDataType> = {
    count: 1,
    response: {
        id: '1',
        isTheUserAdmin: true,
        data: {
           linkTypes: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
           folderTypesIds: [1, 2, 3],
        }
    }
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA2mILMdEAJQgGcAHQ0iAHgBUA+ZAbwFgAoZL5BdAV3AAuZCD4BbAEbQA3B27IoZSiGrC6HAL4cOoSLEQoAguWAkKVWoxZzuwACbDSYKKADmszrdJ0AFhACq1FCGdmKgwhLoWBBwIB7ydnBgcGoeWuwcYACe5CgA4hAg0MAI9EwAvGhYOHgExEoWNMamDSqWDAweOuDQ8EjIALJZACJJcHQ5KGyemKAA1hO5pI7ObgDaALo2MFh20ItkAJJ2yyLiUlCbmtrsvCpgyOgSAFbCBUUupUOjyQcV1p4uLwBGBhABGAA0Ni4inMbWE03k8nswgA5GDUVDAUjgN4-IFoCEwiBhM4+BAsUjuIlkgjoVSuLMQAtJqc1qi4JjkKiJFzUQhURtKQzuDtMHsoAdSMc2ZDkAAmCHIADMQvp8nSGs0QA)